# PHP: Edit JSON string, pass variable value

Tags: php, json, string

I'm making a web app to create issues on my GitHub repo, the problem is I can't use the JSON string below this text because the GitHub API responds with "Cannot parse JSON".

I tried this code, this gave me the parse error (because single ticks (') are **not** working with JSON):

```php
$jsonin = "{'title': '$mytitle','body': '$subject','labels': ['TEST']}";
$exec = shell_exec("curl -u username:AUTHTOKEN  --data '$jsonin' https://api.github.com/repos/username/reponame/issues");
```

This code is working perfectly (it creates the issue), except it is (obviously) passing the string **not** the variable value (**$mytitle** and **$subject**):

```php
$jsonin = '{"title": "$mytitle","body": "$subject","labels": ["TEST"]}';
$exec = shell_exec("curl -u username:AUTHTOKEN  --data '$jsonin' https://api.github.com/repos/username/reponame/issues");
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do not create your own json! You'll always end up with some sort of syntax error. Instead, create an array and use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Also json string is __usually__ created via `json_encode`.

Comment: why are you sending the command to the shell and not use the curl php functions ?